# What series is this depiction of Araragi Karen referring to?

Tags: monogatari-series

In episode 8 of Nisemonogatari, we briefly see Araragi Karen drawn like this:

[image]

This looked a lot like some anime (or possibly a character from an anime or manga) I'd seen within the last ten years or so while in Asia, so I have the feeling this drawing style was supposed to allude to something. (Possibly [Dr. Slump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Slump)? I'm not sure since I don't think I ever saw the anime, and I could easily have mixed it up with something else.)

That said, this also looks "generic" enough that's possible that this is only a shift in drawing style. But then right before this image, there's a drawing of Karen that looked  like (to me anyway: I have a feeling I'm wrong about this) an imitation of the titular character of [Chibi Maruko-chan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibi_Maruko-chan), so I'm not sure:

[image]

Moreover, I remember seeing something that looked very much like a parody of [Peko-chan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujiya_Co.) in an earlier episode, though unfortunately I don't remember which one it was:

[image]

Is this (the first image, I mean) supposed to be an allusion to some other anime series, and if so, what is it referring to?

Comment: The first pic reminds me of Mayumi Muroyama's style, but I'm not sure it's referring to her work...

Answer (score 2):

Many of the slapstick moments in the Monogatari Series are depicted in a way that closely resembles the art style of [Doraemon](http://www.anisearch.com/anime/1840,doraemon). In fact, I vaguely remember a scene where the protagonist of the Monogatari Series, [Koyomi Araragi](http://www.anisearch.com/character/5174,koyomi-araragi), complains about too many Doraemon references.

The whole Doraemon series is very extensive with a myriad of movies and specials and not to mention the [second season](http://www.anisearch.com/anime/540,doraemon-1979) which sports a whopping 1787 episodes.

Comment: I've definitely seen shots that were very reminescent of _Doraemon_---there was one instance in one of the early segments of the series where one of the Araragi sisters was drawn like Suneo---but I'm not sure here of whether the resemblance is strong enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is 100% correct, but when I saw it, I presumed it was a reference to Dragonball and Akira Toriyama's early art style.

[image]
[image]

In particular, It reminded me of Krillin who is frequently drawn without a nose.

[image]

I can't seem to find a perfect example on Google, but I remember this style often in the original series. One point to note though is that the lines around the eyes don't go around fully.

I haven't seen Dr. slump, but as it's the same authour it makes sense you drew these parallels too.